# create multiple img tags in a div through the DOM

Tags: javascript, image, dom

I am not knowing on how exactly how to proceed after I have created my div and assigned it an id. I can't use JQuery or another library of JavaScript.

So far I have

```
var imageTabsDiv = document.createElement('div');
    imageTabsDiv.setAttribute('id', 'imageTabs');
```

but then I hit a mental block and don't know how to proceed after this.

It should look like this in the html

```
<div id="imageTabs">
   <img src="images/pics/imageTab01" />
   <img src="images/pics/imageTab02" />
   <img src="images/pics/imageTab03" />
   <img src="images/pics/imageTab04" />
</div>
```

I would like some advice or hint on how to proceed from here accessing the div tag threw the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick `for` loop to create your `img` elements and assign the proper source, then append to the `div`

```
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "images/pics/imageTab0" + i;
    imageTabsDiv.appendChild(img);
}
```

And of course, append that newly created `div` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the insight into my problem. I have tried it and it works great.

Comment: Always happy to help, be sure to mark the answer as Accepted when ya can!